# Inserting text at specific point in a list generated using #each

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to find a nice, Meteor-style way to handle this issue.

I have a set of Mongo documents sorted by date that I can easily display in a list:

```html
<template name="logbook">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <div>
      {{#each entries}}
         {{> Entry}}
      {{/each}}
   </div>
</template>
```

Now, each time the year changes, I'd like to output it, so that I get something like this:

> #### 2014
>
> doc 1
>
> doc 2
>
> #### 2013
>
> doc 3
>
> doc 4
>
> doc 5
>
> etc.

This this is Meteor, I'd like the list to be reactive. If a new document arrives then it should be inserted in the right place in the list, and the year added if necessary.

Can anyone suggest a sensible approach to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use helper that will check if year is the same as in the last record, if not - he will output it, something like

```
<template name="Entry">
   {{year}}
   {{data}}
</template>
```

And in js

```
year: function(){
  //operations that will return year to some variable, for example year_variable
  if(global_variable===undefined){
    global_variable=year_variable;
    return year_variable;
  }
  if(global_variable===year_variable) return false;
  else return year_variable;
}
```

There is no need to make it global tho, you can use sessions for it

Answer (score 0):

This may not be precisely what you are looking for with respect to naming conventions, but it will give you an idea of how I would approach this problem:

1. Create a list of unique years
2. For each year, render a template (logbook)
3. Within each logbook, iterate over all of the entries for that year

Here is a complete working solution:

### app.html

```html
<body>
  {{#each years}}
    {{> logbook}}
  {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="logbook">
   <h2>{{year}}</h2>
   <ol>
    {{#each entries}}
      <li>{{text}}</li>
    {{/each}}
   </ol>
</template>
```

### app.js

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // create a client-side collection for testing
  Entries = new Mongo.Collection(null);

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    // insert some data in the wrong order to test sorting
    Entries.insert({text: 'doc6', date: new Date('1/3/2013')});
    Entries.insert({text: 'doc4', date: new Date('1/1/2013')});
    Entries.insert({text: 'doc5', date: new Date('1/2/2013')});

    Entries.insert({text: 'doc3', date: new Date('1/3/2014')});
    Entries.insert({text: 'doc1', date: new Date('1/1/2014')});
    Entries.insert({text: 'doc2', date: new Date('1/2/2014')});
  });

  Template.body.helpers({
    years: function() {
      // return a list of unique sorted objects with a year field
      return _.chain(Entries.find().fetch())
        // pluck out the dates
        .pluck('date')
        // convert each date to a year
        .map(function(date) {return date.getFullYear();})
        // sort the years in reverse order
        .sortBy(function(year) {return -year;})
        // find only the unique values
        .uniq(true)
        // '2014' -> {year: '2014'}
        .map(function(year) {return {year: year};})
        .value();
    }
  });

  Template.logbook.helpers({
    entries: function() {
      var year = this.year;
      var entries = Entries.find({}, {sort: {date: 1}}).fetch();

      // return a list of entries only for this year
      return _.filter(entries, function(entry) {
        return entry.date.getFullYear() === year;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi David. That's nice, but it doesn't play well with Meteor's reactivity. If I insert a single entry then the entire list will need to be redrawn.

Comment: At this point I'm thinking that observing the collection is the way to go. When items are added/removed I can flag a document to mark it as "printing the year" when needed. Then in the each template I can print the year if the flag is set.

Comment: With the old spark rendering engine, it would have rerendered the entire list if you inserted any items but blaze does the correct thing even if you return a non-cursor from a helper. You can test this by console logging in logbook's `rendered` callback. You can further optimize the queries by denormalizing the year into its own field. I think using an `observe` just for this seems like overkill but hey it's your code. :)